# How to overwrite a array with a second array, only if the specific index is a valid number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, merge, concatenation

I have 2 arrays:

```
var array1 = [1,4,8,10,12]
var array2 = [3,2,undefined,9,undefined]
```

So, I need to have an result array where all values of `array1` have been replaced by the values of `array2`, but only in case the specific index of `array2` is a not `undefined` (a valid number). The value of the index of `array1` should persist in that case.

The result should be:

```
resultArray = [3, 2, 8, 9, 12]
```

I couldn't get it work.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check explicit for `undefined` and take the value of `array1` for mapping.

```js
var array1 = [1, 4, 8, 10, 12],
    array2 = [3, 2, undefined, 9, undefined],
    result = array2.map((v, i) => v === undefined ? array1[i] : v);
    
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 const resultArray = array2.map((el, i) => isNaN(el) ? array1[i] : el);
```

Note that this will replace `undefined` but not `null`, due to some very funny language design.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using the function **[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**

```js
var array1 = [1, 4, 8, 10, 12],
    array2 = [3, 2, undefined, 9, undefined],
    result = Array.from(array2, (n, i) => isNaN(n) ? array1[i] : n);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```